# Twitter API - how to check if user A follows user B

Tags: php, twitter

My problem is quite strange (at least to me) as I have a request URL that works in the console but throws the `Sorry, that page does not exist` error in my php script, even though the connection is up and running.

So this

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_secret']);
$user = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
print_r($user);
```

works great, the $user data is printed out on the screen.

However, I am unable to check a friendship status as:

```
$x = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/show.json?source_id=707482092&target_id=755811768&target_screen_name=assetspersonifi');
```

As I get the error.

**When I put this request into the Twitter API console, it gives back the json** that I don't receive in my php code.

I'm using [Abraham's twitteroauth library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) but this does not work either:

```
$follows_faelazo = $connection->get('friendships/exists', array('user_a' => 'blfarago', 'user_b' => 'faelazo'));
if(!$follows_faelazo){
    echo 'You are NOT following @faelazo!';
    $connection->post('friendships/create', array('screen_name' => 'faelazo'));
} else {
    print_r($follows_faelazo);
}

stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Sorry, that page does not exist [code] => 34 ) ) )
```

I read that `friendships/exists` API is no longer supported by the Twitter API and I should use `friendships/show` but how if it's not working as you see above?

To prove that everything else is working, I can follow others with

```
$connection->post('friendships/create', array('screen_name' => 'faelazo'));
```

Why?

Comment: This is a clearly defined question showing what I need and what I tried, so why the downvote?

Comment: 1. Make sure that you've updated the API version variable (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/src/TwitterOAuth.php#L18) 2. Consider using the users ids (`source_id`,`target_id`). 3. Can you be sure that those users truly exist?

Answer (score 6):

I found a way. [Here's the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friendships/show)

```
$following = $connection->get('friendships/show', array(
    'source_screen_name' => $_SESSION['username'],
    'target_screen_name' => $screen_name_to_follow,
));
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be

```
$following = $connection->get('friendships/lookup', array('screen_name' => $screen_name_to_follow));
```

Look it up in [Twitter doc](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friendships/lookup).